# TRegistry::KeyExists() fails when key is a componentID like {ABC-...} [Rad Studio]

Tags: c++builder-2009

In RAD Studio 2009, `KeyExists()` works without the ID `{1D30003C-A1G4-22E5-CGSH-833A4E1X1234}`. I copied the ID from the Registry Editor. Does the ID need to be formatted differently somehow?

Path copied directly from Registry Editor:

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1D30003C-A1G4-22E5-CGSH-833A4E1X1234}`

```
TRegistry* reg = new TRegistry(KEY_READ);
reg->RootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
if (reg->KeyExists(L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\{1D30003C-A1G4-22E5-CGSH-833A4E1X1234}"))
{
   ShowMessage("successful");
}
reg->CloseKey();
reg->Free();
```

Can anyone here help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. I need "KEY_READ **| KEY_WOW64_64KEY**" to get access for IDs. I don't understand why, but now its working.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view

In Rad Studio KEY_WOW64_64KEY was not mentioned
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.Access

Comment: "*I don't understand why*" - because you are running a 32bit app on a 64bit Windows, and the key in question only exists in the 64bit view of the Registry, not in the 32bit view, so you have to ask `TRegistry` to open the 64bit view.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the explanation. Rad Studio should point that out in the manual :)